# How to make .foregroundColor accept UInt32 hexadecimals using an extension in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, hex, extension-methods

I'm trying to change the foreground color of an object using a hexadecimal, but .foregroundColor only accepts values of type Color. I've heard somewhere that you're able to modify .foregroundColor to accept values of type UInt32, but I am unsure of how to go about doing that. I'm new to SwiftUI and programming in general and there was nothing else I could find online that would help (or make sense), so anything would appreciated.

I'm not sure what I'm doing or where to even start (which will explain the lack of code), but I've tried this and got the error "Expected '{' in extension" and "Expected type name in extension declaration" :

extension .foregroundColor {

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend the underlying `Color` struct, not `.foregroundColor` which is the view modifier.

But better still would be to extend the `ShapeStyle` protocol that `Color` conforms to, but only in the specific case where it is used as a `Color`.

You can do this with a custom init that takes an `Int` (in either decimal or hex notation), and then mask and bit shift this value to get the individual color components.  You will then need to convert them to a value between 0 and 1 by dividing by 0xFF (i.e. 255) for use by the standard `Color.init(red:, green: blue:)`

```
extension ShapeStyle where Self == Color {
   init(fromInt value: Int) {
      let red = CGFloat((value & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255
      let green = CGFloat((value & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255
      let blue = CGFloat(value & 0x0000FF) / 255
      
      self.init(red: red, green: green, blue: blue)
   }
}
```

You can then use the this anywhere that takes a `Color`, such as in your question with `.foregroundColor`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("I'm red text")
         .foregroundColor(Color(fromInt: 0xff0000))
   }
}
```

Note: a hex color string should really be a four part string; the three colors, as above, and the alpha channel as the final 2 hex digits.  In this case you'd need to extend the mask by the extra characters and bit shift each value by a further 8 bits.